# XML Color for area outside rectangle's curved edges

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, shapes

I am making a rectangle for the background of a RelativeLayout and was wondering how I could make the area outside of the rounded edges of this rectangle to also be darker_grey.  Currently, only the inside of this rectangle is darker_grey

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by switching to a `layer-list` drawable, and layering your shape on top of a solid colour, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for the background to be an image too?

Comment: @Paradox Yes - the `<item>` tag has a `drawable` property you can use to reference another drawable, like this: `<item android:drawable="@ref..." />`

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to implement background color to any view using shape:**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"/>
```

Please decide view width and height based on your requirement.

**It will look like**:

[image]